# Finding a name within a list

Tags: python

Basically I have an array of customers consisting of their ID and name; it looks like this:

```
array = [['B1', 'Bob'], ['B2', 'Jim'], ['B3', 'Jill']]
```

I'm making a function which takes in a name/id and sees if it is existing in the array. So far I've had no luck.

This is what I have so far:

```
def findPerson(name):
    for a in array:
        id = a[0]
        array_name = a[1]
        
    if (name == id) or (name == array_name):
        print("Found the person!")
    else:
        print("Could not find the person!")

findPerson('Bob')
findPerson('B3')
findPerson('B14')
```

The output shows this:

```
Could not find the person!
Found the person!
Could not find the person!
```

How can I fix this issue? Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach has two problems. Do you realize what they are? In other words, what's stopping you from solving this yourself? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)?

Comment: The main problem with your example is you are only checking for a match after the for loop is finished. So only the last element in the array is being checked for a match.

Answer (score 2):

This will just check if there is a match in the array:

```
def findPerson(name):
    array = [['B1', 'Bob'], ['B2', 'Jim'], ['B3', 'Jill']]
        
    if any(name in a for a in array):
        print("Found the person!")
    else:
        print("Could not find the person!")

findPerson('Bob')
findPerson('B3')
findPerson('B14')
```

Returns:

```
Found the person!
Found the person!
Could not find the person!
```

Assuming you want to be able to do something with the found persons array data, how about this:

```
def findPerson(name):
    array = [['B1', 'Bob'], ['B2', 'Jim'], ['B3', 'Jill']]
    found_person = None

    for index, a in enumerate(array):
        
        if name in a:
            print(f"Found the person at position {index} in array")
            found_person = a
            return found_person

    print("Could not find the person!")

findPerson('Bob')
findPerson('B3')
findPerson('B14')
```

returns:

```
Found the person at position 0 in array
Found the person at position 2 in array
Could not find the person!
```

Can we make this simpler? This will also return multiple matches. What if there's two Bobs?

```
def findPerson(name):
    array = [['B1', 'Bob'], ['B2', 'Jim'], ['B3', 'Jill'], ['B4', 'Bob']]

    found_person = [a for a in array if name in a]

    if found_person:
        print(f"Found {found_person}")
    else:
        print("Could not find the person!")

findPerson('Bob')
findPerson('B3')
findPerson('B14')
```

returns:

```
Found [['B1', 'Bob'], ['B4', 'Bob']]
Found [['B3', 'Jill']]
Could not find the person!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can numpy to do this task.

```
import numpy as np
array = [['B1', 'Bob'], ['B2', 'Jim'], ['B3', 'Jill']]

def findPerson(name):
    if name in np.asarray(array):
        print('Found the person!')
    else:
        print('Could not find the person!')

findPerson('Bob')
findPerson('B3')
findPerson('B14')
```

Output:

```
Found the person!
Found the person!
Could not find the person!
```

Comment: Numpy is overkill for this